# Android Studio: "cannot resolve symbol 'recyclerView'" but the RecyclerView symbol does work

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm having this wierd problem where i am trying to add an itemDecorator for my recyclerview, but for some reason Android Studio wont aknoledge the "recyclerView" in the code "recyclerView.addItemDecorator(itemDecoration);" it should be noted that RecyclerView with capital letter "R" does work.
I have also importet the RecyclerView class in the begining of my activity, and i have implemented the RecyclerView in my gradle build.
Maybe i have done something wrong, or misunderstood something:

Here is a bit of my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


                    RecyclerView rvCalculations = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCalculations);
                    //calculations = Calculation.createCalculationsList(50);
                    calculations.add(0, new Calculation("  " + mNameEditText.getText()));
                    CalculationsAdapter adapter = new CalculationsAdapter(calculations);
                    rvCalculations.setAdapter(adapter);
                    rvCalculations.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                    rvCalculations.scrollToPosition(0);
                    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.addItemDecorator(itemDecoration);



                    if (!mNameEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.ErrorMessageNameCalculation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.SuccesMessageNameCalculation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                }
            });
```

Everything else works, exept from this line "recyclerView.addItemDecorator(itemDecoration);"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recyclerView.addItemDecorator(itemDecoration);
^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^
```

should be

```
rvCalculations.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^
```

When invoking a method on an instance you name the instance, not the class.  Also, the method name is `addItemDecoration`, not `addItemDecorator`.

Comment: i have tried that, but then it cannot resolve the method to the RecyclerView class? :/

Comment: The method name is `addItemDecoration` (answer edited).  Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) before posting.

Comment: Well thank you alot, guess i have looked too much on this screen now and, miss obviuos stuff :)